# IIS6 Wildcard mapping lost

Tags: iis-6, deployment

I'm trying to configure IIS6 with wildcard mappings for an ASP.Net MVC application, so I found [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx) tutorial, however, checking the mappings association,

[mappings image](http://img192.imageshack.us/img192/9435/iis6.gif)

I checked my IIS6 Manager is different from that of the tutorial, and given this, i can't associate a wildcard mapping.

I am using IIS 6 Manager downloaded from Microsoft site a few days ago.

any thoughts or ideas? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a wildcard mapping on IIS5.1; just map `*.*` to aspnet_isapi.dll like any other handler. (uncheck verify file exists).

Edit- there is apparently more to it to get the actual code to work- see this stackoverflow question:

[Deploy ASP.Net MVC on IIS 5.1 ( Windows XP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301359/deploy-asp-net-mvc-on-iis-5-1-windows-xp)

Answer (score 1):

Your screen shot looks very similar to mine when i try to manage my IIS6 servers from my XP workstation, are you trying to manage the server remotely?

If so, have you tried RDPing to the actual IIS server and opening the mappings console.

I just spot checked all my IIS6 servers and they all include the Wildcare application maps section.

EDIT:

IIS5.1 doesn't support Wildcard mappings.

IIS version is tied to the OS.

- IIS5 = Windows 2000
- IIS5.1 = Windows XP
- IIS6 = Windows 2003
- IIS7 = Windows 2008 / Vista

You either need to throw your development code on a windows 2003/2008 server, or upgrade your workstation to vista.

Comment: Yeah you're right, i'm managing server's IIS from my XP machine, RDP'ing effectively shows wildcard mapping... however, Local IIS (XP) doesn't have wildcard mapping either, how can I configure it locally?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the wildcard mapping section on my local IIS either.